# Create routes from a set of values

Tags: reactjs, react-router, switch-statement

I would like to set the routes for the languages my webpage accepts, something like

```
import Component from '../src/component/component';
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/es" component={(props) => <Component language="es" />}/>
    <Route exact path="/en" component={ (props) => <Component language="en" />}/>
</Switch>
```

But the languages that are accepted depend on a configuration file, and more can be added in the future. So I would like to be able to add these routes depending on the values of this file.

The option I've seen is to add the routes like this:
    
         }/>
    
But don't want to accept any possibility, just some the ones I need.

Is there a way to create routes to accept several possible routes but not any route?

thanks.

Comment: What is the parent component of these routes? Are they in a `Switch`?

Comment: Yes they are, I added it

Comment: how do you define which component must render

Comment: You can see it now

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple mapping for the accepted languages and then loop over it to render the Routes

```
const languages = ['es', 'en'];

import Component from '../src/component/component';
...
<Switch>
   {languages.map(lang => {
      return <Route
         key={lang}
         exact 
         path={`/${lang}`} 
         component={(props) => <Component {...props} language={lang} />}/>
   })}
</Switch>
```

Comment: Putting backticks it gives al error "SyntaxError: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text "

Comment: Please look at the edit. I missed adding `{}` around it

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch`-component in react router will render the first component that does not return null, so we can hijack this behavior to accomplish what you need.

First, we define an object mapping languages to components:

```
const langs = {
  en: ComponentEn,
  es: ComponentEs,
};
```

Then we can define a language selector component:

```
const LanguageSelector=({match})=>{
  const language = match.params.language
  const Component = langs[language];
  if(Component) return <Component/>
  else return null;
}
```

Now we can use it in our routing

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/:language" component={LanguageSelector}/>
  <DefaultComponent/>
</Switch>
```

Of course you can replace the `DefaultComponent` with whatever you want